# Scrape a javascript variable from a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, web, web-scraping

I am scraping a site with beautiful soup but all the content is hidden inside a script inside a js variable like this:

I can't seem to find any solution to this other than using selenium which in this case is not an option, I won't go into detail why but it just doesn't work. I can already scrape it by getting the insid eof the script tag and then using eval() on it but that introduces a few problems (unexpected indent, unwanted functions) I can use python, javascript and maybe C# if anything there helps.

Expected behaviour - whatever makes me get the info (the variable in the last line) into any of those 3 languages (preferably python).

The code (sorry for the formating but i cant since its so long, it isnt even the full variable, its huge):

barLoadGoogleFont('Open Sans');         barCssLoad('/global/pics/js/jquery/royalSlider/skins/universal/rs-universal.css?v=e449c4');         barCssLoad('/global/pics/css/material-icons.css?v=e6d856');         barCssLoad('/user/pics/css/user.css?v=eced9d');
barCssLoad('/user/pics/css/userIcons.css?v=6f9a03');
barCssLoad('/timeline/pics/css/timeline.css?v=8ec2ca');         barJsLibraryLoad('/global/pics/js/jquery/jquery.royalslider.min.js?v=515a43');      barJsLibraryLoad('/anketa/pics/js/utilsAnketa.js?v=9383d5');        barJsLibraryLoad('/znamky/pics/js/utilsZnamky.js?v=7afc9e');        barJsLibraryLoad('/exam/pics/js/utilsExam.js?v=033d55');        barJsLibraryLoad('/timeline/pics/js/utilsTimeline.js?v=29cf0e');                    barJsLibraryLoad('/timeline/pics/js/timelineItemCreator.js?v=c37c99');      barJsLibraryLoad('/timeline/pics/js/timelineInputbox.js?v=2fde70');         barJsLibraryLoad('/timeline/pics/js/timelineViewer.js?v=f35e45');
barJsLibraryLoad('/user/pics/js/DailyPlan.js?v=e81fb9');        barJsLibraryLoad('/user/pics/js/userHomeEtest.js?v=6166f3');

$j(document).ready(function() {                                                                                     $j('#jwbcddd3da_md').userhome({"items":[{"timelineid":"2140963","timestamp":"2020-12-09 09:59:13","reakcia_na":"692638","typ":"h_clearplany","user":"Plan5077","target_user":null,"user_meno":"Kvarta aj2","ineid":"clearplany","text":"","cas_pridania":"2020-12-09 09:59:13","cas_udalosti":null,"data":"null","vlastnik":"Ucitel8678605","vlastnik_meno":"Barbora Drugajov\u00e1","pocet_reakcii":"0","posledna_reakcia":"","pomocny_zaznam":"1","removed":"0","cas_pridania_btc":"2020-12-09 09:59:13","posledna_reakcia_btc":null},{"timelineid":"2287814","timestamp":"2020-12-09 09:59:12","reakcia_na":"2290613","typ":"h_dailyplan","user":"Trieda8694210","target_user":null,"user_meno":"Kvarta A","ineid":"daily2020-12-09","text":"","cas_pridania":"2020-12-09 09:59:12","cas_udalosti":null,"data":"[]","vlastnik":"Ucitel8678605","vlastnik_meno":"Barbora Drugajov\u00e1","pocet_reakcii":"0","posledna_reakcia":"","pomocny_zaznam":"1","removed":"0","cas_pridania_btc":"2020-12-09 09:59:12","posledna_reakcia_btc":null},{"timelineid":"1439827","timestamp":"2020-12-09 08:56:57","reakcia_na":null,"typ":"h_clearplany","user":"*","target_user":null,"user_meno":"Cel\u00e1 \u0161kola","ineid":"clearplany","text":"","cas_pridania":"2020-12-09 08:56:57","cas_udalosti":null,"data":"null","vlastnik":"Ucitel16434","vlastnik_meno":"Ivor Dian","pocet_reakcii":"0","posledna_reakcia":"","pomocny_zaznam":null,"removed":"0","cas_pridania_btc":"2020-12-09 08:56:57","posledna_reakcia_btc":null},{"timelineid":"2290324","timestamp":"2020-12-09 08:37:22","reakcia_na":null,"typ":"sprava","user":"CustPlan5075","target_user":null,"user_meno":"Kvarta A+Kvarta B - nj4 \u00b7 nemeck\u00fd jazyk","ineid":null,"text":"Ahojte, zajtra...

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: is this within a `<script>` tag in the html?

Comment: @chitown88 i cant it is after login page and yes this is inside a script tag

Comment: you should have it on your email, let me know if its there

Answer (score 0):

Ok, little tough to debug without actually working with it. But you'll need to pull out that json structure. You can do it with splits. So this is sort of a generic code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json


url = 'www.thesite.com'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
    if '.userhome({' in script.text:
        json_str = script.text
        data = json_str.split('.userhome(')[-1]
    
        loop=True
        while loop == True:
            try:
                jsonData = json.loads(data)
                loop = False
                break
            except:
                data = data.rsplit(';',1)[0]
    
rows = []
for row in jsonData['items']:
    rows.append(row)

table = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```